# Docker run is unable to locate the directory

Tags: linux, bash, docker, azure-devops

I've built a docker image, `docker build -t dockeragent:latest .` but can't seem to trigger the container to run. The command: `docker run -e AZP_URL=<obfuscate> -e AZP_TOKEN=<obfuscate> -e AZP_AGENT_NAME=mydockeragent dockeragent:latest` produces the following error: `exec ./start.sh: no such file or directory`.

I understand that the `start.sh` script is called by the `Dockerfile` and I've ensured that the `Dockerfile` is in the same directory as the start.sh script. I've also tested referencing the start.sh script by using interpolation to point to the absolute path pointing to the start.sh script. Example:
`ENTRYPOINT [ "${pwd}/start.sh" ]`

Any ideas on what parameter has been misconfigured? The files are directly copied from Micorosft's guide on [building self-hosted agents with Docker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/docker?view=azure-devops)

For reference, please see the below `Dockerfile` and associated `start.sh`

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get update
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get upgrade -y

RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y -qq --no-install-recommends \
    apt-transport-https \
    apt-utils \
    ca-certificates \
    curl \
    git \
    iputils-ping \
    jq \
    lsb-release \
    software-properties-common

RUN curl -sL https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCLIDeb | bash

# Can be 'linux-x64', 'linux-arm64', 'linux-arm', 'rhel.6-x64'.
ENV TARGETARCH=linux-x64

WORKDIR /azp

COPY ./start.sh .
RUN chmod +x start.sh

ENTRYPOINT [ "./start.sh" ]
```

`start.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

if [ -z "$AZP_URL" ]; then
  echo 1>&2 "error: missing AZP_URL environment variable"
  exit 1
fi

if [ -z "$AZP_TOKEN_FILE" ]; then
  if [ -z "$AZP_TOKEN" ]; then
    echo 1>&2 "error: missing AZP_TOKEN environment variable"
    exit 1
  fi

  AZP_TOKEN_FILE=/azp/.token
  echo -n $AZP_TOKEN > "$AZP_TOKEN_FILE"
fi

unset AZP_TOKEN

if [ -n "$AZP_WORK" ]; then
  mkdir -p "$AZP_WORK"
fi

export AGENT_ALLOW_RUNASROOT="1"

cleanup() {
  if [ -e config.sh ]; then
    print_header "Cleanup. Removing Azure Pipelines agent..."

    # If the agent has some running jobs, the configuration removal process will fail.
    # So, give it some time to finish the job.
    while true; do
      ./config.sh remove --unattended --auth PAT --token $(cat "$AZP_TOKEN_FILE") && break

      echo "Retrying in 30 seconds..."
      sleep 30
    done
  fi
}

print_header() {
  lightcyan='\033[1;36m'
  nocolor='\033[0m'
  echo -e "${lightcyan}$1${nocolor}"
}

# Let the agent ignore the token env variables
export VSO_AGENT_IGNORE=AZP_TOKEN,AZP_TOKEN_FILE

print_header "1. Determining matching Azure Pipelines agent..."

AZP_AGENT_PACKAGES=$(curl -LsS \
    -u user:$(cat "$AZP_TOKEN_FILE") \
    -H 'Accept:application/json;' \
    "$AZP_URL/_apis/distributedtask/packages/agent?platform=$TARGETARCH&top=1")

AZP_AGENT_PACKAGE_LATEST_URL=$(echo "$AZP_AGENT_PACKAGES" | jq -r '.value[0].downloadUrl')

if [ -z "$AZP_AGENT_PACKAGE_LATEST_URL" -o "$AZP_AGENT_PACKAGE_LATEST_URL" == "null" ]; then
  echo 1>&2 "error: could not determine a matching Azure Pipelines agent"
  echo 1>&2 "check that account '$AZP_URL' is correct and the token is valid for that account"
  exit 1
fi

print_header "2. Downloading and extracting Azure Pipelines agent..."

curl -LsS $AZP_AGENT_PACKAGE_LATEST_URL | tar -xz & wait $!

source ./env.sh

print_header "3. Configuring Azure Pipelines agent..."

./config.sh --unattended \
  --agent "${AZP_AGENT_NAME:-$(hostname)}" \
  --url "$AZP_URL" \
  --auth PAT \
  --token $(cat "$AZP_TOKEN_FILE") \
  --pool "${AZP_POOL:-Default}" \
  --work "${AZP_WORK:-_work}" \
  --replace \
  --acceptTeeEula & wait $!

print_header "4. Running Azure Pipelines agent..."

trap 'cleanup; exit 0' EXIT
trap 'cleanup; exit 130' INT
trap 'cleanup; exit 143' TERM

chmod +x ./run-docker.sh

# To be aware of TERM and INT signals call run.sh
# Running it with the --once flag at the end will shut down the agent after the build is executed
./run-docker.sh "$@" & wait $!
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you tried SSHing to the container and check if the file is there?

Comment: I tested your configuration and I could not reproduce this error. Your script is copied under `/azp/start.sh` and then executed without file location issue.

Comment: @MartinTovmassian Thanks Marting. Does that mean I need to explicitly set my entrypoint within the dockerfile to `ENTRYPOINT = ["/azp/start.sh"]` ?

Comment: @mar0ne Thanks for your response. I'll definitely try that. The logs I reviewed were not very verbose and just stated the file/directory start.sh couldn't be found. I'll get back to you on this one cheers.

Comment: Are you on a Windows host?  Is there a possibility that the script file has DOS-style CR+LF line endings?

Answer (score 1):

Check the Dockerfile and Start.sh file. The settings should be correct.

Refer to this doc: [Linux Docker container agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/docker?view=azure-devops#linux)

> Save the following content to ~/dockeragent/start.sh, making sure to use Unix-style (LF) line endings:

The start.sh need to use `Linux LF` line endings when creating Linux Docker Container Agent.

When you create the start.sh in windows system, it will use `Windows CRLF` line endings.

You can convert the Start.sh file from Windows CRLF to Linux LF in this Online site: [LF and CRLF converter online](https://app.execeratics.com/LFandCRLFonline/?l=en)  Then you can run the same command to create the Pipeline agent.

Or you can directly create the files in Linux system.

Answer (score 1):

You can run this and exec into pod check you run file start.sh

```
docker run -e AZP_URL=<obfuscate> -e AZP_TOKEN=<obfuscate> -e AZP_AGENT_NAME=mydockeragent dockeragent:latest --entrypoint sh
```